# If line is longer than x chars cut and add string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am all new to bash and i'm trying to solve one problem.
I know there is already answer to similar question, but that answer is too complicated.

I have a variable with multiple lines and i need to cut each line that is longer than 40 characters and add "...: " after it.

But if the line is shorter than 40 chars i need to make it long 40 characters and add only "   : "

So it looks like this:

```
var=this line is longer than 40 characters so it needs to be cut
but this line is shorter
```

And i need it to look like this:

```
echo "$var"
this line is longer than 40 characters s...: 
but this line is shorter                   :
```

And in my actual variable are 10 lines overall

Comment: your second expected line has 44 characters `but this line is shorter                   :`

Comment: It has 40 characters but three spaces and : are added at the end instead of adding "...: "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf` in `awk`:

```
awk 'length > 40{$0 = substr($0, 1, 40) "..."} {printf "%-43s:\n", $0}' <<< "$var"

this line is longer than 40 characters s...:
but this line is shorter                   :
```

Or make it accept argument from command line:

```
awk -v n=40 -v r='...' 'length > n{$0 = substr($0, 1, n) r}
{printf "%-" n + length(r) "s:\n", $0}' <<< "$var"

this line is longer than 40 characters s...:
but this line is shorter                   :
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: @anubhava, this is a  good answer for this question. Can you make it more generalisable by replacing the 43 by a variable? I mean allow for variable right padding.

Comment: Good point @VM17 I added a generalized version of same command in answer.

Answer (score 0):

***AWK*** approach:

```
echo $var | awk '{printf("%-40s"((length($0)>40)?"...":"   ")":\n", substr($0,1,40))}'
```

The output:

```
this line is longer than 40 characters s...:
but this line is shorter                   :
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we can stay in bash:

```
var='this line is longer than 40 characters so it needs to be cut
but this line is shorter'

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do
    if (( ${#line} > 36 ))
    then
        line="${line:0:36}...:"
    else
        (( diff = 40 - ${#line} ))
        printf -v line "%s%${diff}s\n" "$line" "...:"
    fi

    echo "$line"
done<<<"$var"
```

Obviously other commands like awk can do it shorter :)

It was also unclear if the whole line was to be 40 characters long or 40 of the line plus the additional '...:'.  Easy enough to change :)